# Hadoop HDFS Storage Location

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I have configured Hadoop using a single node cluster using Eclipse. 
And I have ample of text files which are to be parsed.
Eclipse provides direct uploading of files into HDFS, but iam unable to find, where exactly this files are stored in my drive.

What iam looking for is the location where HDFS is configured. So that I can directly paste my text files into that folder.

Comment: Look into the plugin manpage maybe that will give you some info as to how it picks up the local files and puts them on HDFS.

Comment: Iam currently beginner to Hadoop , so can you please tell me how to look into plugin manpage ?

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse to work on Hadoop.  How did you set it up? I assumed you have used a plugin (can be a bad wild guess).

Comment: **Yes** . I have used hadoop-plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is set in the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property, which defaults to `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data` (see details [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)).

However, you cannot just put files there, since HDFS would not auto-discover them. Inserting a file HDFS involves metadata operations at the namenode too. It is not just as simple as copying a file. The file needs to be divided into blocks, and the proper metadata data structures need to be updated in the name node. You should keep using the interface that Eclipse provides you to upload files to HDFS, or you can do it in the command-line (using `hdfs dfs -put`).